# Cannot import javafx fxml class

Tags: javafx, fxml, importerror

Using the FXML project template in netbeans, I've been experiencing an issue with defining the FX controller in my FXML file.

- The main class, fxml document and fxml controller are all in the same package: "login".
- I am importing the controller into the fxml document using it's fully qualified name.
- Error occurs at the import line: "Class login.MyController does not exist."

**FXML Document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import login.MyController?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="login.MyController">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="-fx-background-color: #091D34;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
        <Polygon fill="#000000b1" layoutX="363.0" layoutY="103.0" points="-50.0, 40.0, 50.0, 40.0, 50.0, -73.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" style="-fx-fill: #133863;" />
        <ButtonBar layoutX="233.0" layoutY="256.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="161.0">
          <buttons>
              <Button layoutX="135.0" layoutY="18.0" minWidth="49.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" text="Login" onAction="#doLogin" />
              <Button layoutX="165.0" layoutY="18.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
          </buttons>
        </ButtonBar>
        <PasswordField layoutX="186.0" layoutY="216.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="273.0" promptText="Password" onKeyPressed="#onEnter" />
        <TextField layoutX="186.0" layoutY="175.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="273.0" promptText="Username" />
        <Text layoutX="253.0" layoutY="76.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-fill: #236AB9;" text="Anatomy Law" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="120.58984375">
           <font>
              <Font name="Aparajita" size="22.0" />
           </font>
        </Text>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller**

```
package login;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class MyController implements Initializable {


@FXML
public void doLogin(Event e){
    System.out.println("do login called");
}

@FXML
public void onEnter(KeyEvent ke){
    if(ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
        System.out.println("on enter called");
        login();
    }
}

private void login(){

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

}
```

}

**Main**

```
package login;

import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {    
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    MyController fxmlController = new MyController();

    fxmlLoader.setController(fxmlController);
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(new URL("C:/.../login/Login.fxml"));

    VBox vbox = fxmlLoader.<VBox>load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

*Note*
I recently tried the following line in my FXML document:

```
<?import login.*?>
```

Which resulted in "package login does not exist."

And

```
<?import MyController?>
```

Which resulted in class does not exist.

So i'm assuming it's some kind of build path error but they're all in the same package. I even added the package that they're in to additional source packages to build from just to make sure but that didn't solve anything. My project layout is the following:

```
Project Name 
    Source Packages 
        login
            Login.fxml
            MyController.java
            Main.java
```

I reviewed the other question postings for this problem but no one seemed to have this specific problem. If I did however miss someone's post with an identical answer, I will gladly take that reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the document you are editing is definitely the document in your package. 
Somehow, in my case I was actually editing a document outside of the package with the same exact name. This is why it couldn't find the controller class when I tried to import it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import it. You have to specify the full name of your controller class though.

In your case it is `login.MyController` so `fx:controller="login.MyController"`.

Though you might have some other problems because I'm not having any issues when i put that import statement in the fxml. It just isn't necessary.

Comment: It will compile but the functions defined and linked to buttons are never called (such as doLogin, defined in mycontroller class) so perhaps even though NetBeans doesn't recognize the import statement, it may in fact still be working regardless? With that being the case, perhaps I simply fudged when creating the FXML file. I'll update my post to include the full FXML code.

Comment: Does your controller gets initialized when you load the fxml?

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm not quite sure what the problem is. I ran system.out.println(MyController.class.getName()); to make sure I was using the fully qualified name and after copying and pasting that name into the FXML doc (they were exactly the same) there was no difference.

Comment: 1. If you specify the controller in fxml you don't have to instantiate it yourself and set as a controller for the FXMLLoader. Loader will take care of it. 2. Initializeable interface is deprecated, FXMLLoader will automatically call an initialize method with no parameters. So you could remove the implement and instead overridding the initialize method just create 'public void initialize()' method and check if it gets called.